# A power series in the space complex

Tags: complex-analysis

I heve question. 
Is this series converges in the complex and please justify.

$$\arcsin z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!z^{2n+1}}{(2^n n!)^2(2n+1)}$$
where $|z|\leq 1$

This is a power series $\arcsin x$.
It is very important to me.

Comment: You can use the ratio test.

Comment: I do not know how to do it. You help me?